# HTTP Guzzle not returning all data

Tags: php, guzzle

I have created a function that contacts a remote API using Guzzle but I cannot get it to return all of the data available.

I call the function here:

```
$arr = array(
    'skip' => 0,
    'take' => 1000,
);
$sims = api_request('sims', $arr);
```

And here is the function, where I have tried the following in my `$response` variable

```
json_decode($x->getBody(), true)

json_decode($x->getBody()->getContents(), true)
```

But neither has shown any more records. It returns 10 records, and I know there are over 51 available that it should be returning.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
function api_request($url, $vars = array(), $type = 'GET') {
    $username = '***';
    $password = '***';
    
    //use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    $client = new Client([
        'auth' => [$username, $password],
    ]);
    
    $auth_header = 'Basic '.$username.':'.$password;
    $headers = ['Authorization' => $auth_header, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'];
    $json_data = json_encode($vars);
    $end_point = 'https://simportal-api.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/';
    
    try {
        $x = $client->request($type, $end_point.$url, ['headers' => $headers, 'body' => $json_data]);
        $response = array(
            'success' => true,
            'response' => // SEE ABOVE //
        );
    } catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        $response = array(
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody(true)),
        );
    }
    
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the documentation on https://simportal-api.azurewebsites.net/Help/Api/GET-api-v1-sims_search_skip_take I assume that the server is not accepting your parameters in the body of that GET request and assuming the default of 10, as it is normal in many applications, get requests tend to only use query string parameters.

In that function I'd try to change it in order to send a body in case of a POST/PUT/PATCH request, and a "query" without json_encode in case of a GET/DELETE request. Example from guzzle documentation:

```
$client->request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org', [
    'query' => ['foo' => 'bar']
]);
```

Source: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters

Comment: so if POST/PUT/PATCH, use `query` then if GET/DELETE, use `json_encode($vars)` ?

Comment: The other way around, query for GET/DELETE, json_encode($vars) for POST/PUT/PATCH. Depending on the API you also may need to pass query parameters the POST/PUT/PATCH requests, so I'd say that the best would be to create a new parameter in your function to receive query parameters, that way you don't have to deal with a lot of logic in that function and you can send both at the same time.